# Adding new subView in UIViewController from didSelectRowAtIndexPath iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10, didselectrowatindexpath, addsubview

I got a problem:

My iPad's main page separated on two views.

1-st - menu (UITableView) (left side);

2-nd - work area (UIViewController) where I change UIView (right side).

App works and looks like a usual social web page.

**AppDelegate.m**

First of all, I init my UIViewControllers for work area and add them to array.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    NSMutableArray *vcs = [NSMutableArray array];

    FriendsForImport *friendsForImport = [[CoreDataHelper helperCoreDataHelper] getSocialAccountInfoByIdSocial:0 withUid:@"myUid"];

    SocialPageViewController *socialPageViewController = [[SocialPageViewController alloc] initWithIdSocial:0 withFriendsForImport:friendsForImport withMyAccount:1];

    UINavigationController *socialPageNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:socialPageViewController];

    NSDictionary *socialPageNavigationControllerDict0 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:socialPageNavigationController, @"vc", [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MainMenuMyPageViewController", nil)], @"title", @"111-user.png", @"image", @"1", @"notification", @"0", @"idSocial",nil];

    [vcs addObject:socialPageNavigationControllerDict0];

        .....init and add to array another......

    Below In this method I init main UIViewController (**iPadSHSidebarViewController**) with UIViewControllers array.

    _sidebariPad = [[iPadSHSidebarViewController alloc] initWithArrayOfVC:vcs];
            self.window.rootViewController = _sidebariPad;
}
```

In main UIViewController 
**iPadSHSidebarViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     //init work area
     _mainViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

     //init menu
     _menuView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width*ksliderMenuWidthKoeff, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     [self.view addSubview:_menuView];
        .....
     //set to work area first UIViewController from array (SocialPageViewController)
     [self changeMain:[[viewsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"vc"]];
}

// for changing UIViewControllers in work area
-(void)changeMain:(UIViewController *)main
{
     [_mainViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
     _mainViewController = main;
     _mainViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(_menuView.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-_menuView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
     [self.view addSubview:_mainViewController.view];   
}

// for opening selected user's page UIViewControllers in work area above all opened UIViewControllers

-(void)setModalInMain:(UIViewController *)modal
{
     modal.view.tag=countTag++; 
     [_mainViewController.view addSubview:modal.view];
}
```

**SocialPageViewController** is user's page and it first what we see in work area when app init .

**SocialPageViewController** got a UIViewTable with friends list. 
When user tap to the row in the friends list, init the new UIViewControler with the data of selected user, using the work area's UIViewControler (iPadSHSidebarViewController) method **setModalInMain**.

**SocialPageViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FriendsForImport *friendsForImport = [_listArrayForOut objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([friendsForImport.active intValue]==1){

        SocialPageViewController *socialPageViewController = [[SocialPageViewController alloc] initWithIdSocial:_idSocial withFriendsForImport:friendsForImport withMyAccount:0];
        socialPageViewController.delegate=self;
        UINavigationController *socialPageNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:socialPageViewController];

        iPadSHSidebarViewController *ipadSHSidebarViewController=(iPadSHSidebarViewController*)XAppDelegate.window.rootViewController;
        [ipadSHSidebarViewController setModalInMain: socialPageNavigationController];
    }
}
```

In iPhone (**iOS8,10**) all works fine.

In iPad (**iOS8**) all works fine

**Screenshot #1**

But in **iOS 10** - when I tap to the row, instead of the user's data page, opens the empty **UIViewController** with the white navigation bar.

*(But if in IOS 10 I try do this in other places (tap to the navigation bar button)  - all work fine).*

**Screenshot #2**

If I try open page from **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** without navigationbar - all work fine. But page open without navigationbar.

**Screenshot #3**

**Why this happen in iOS10 and just in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?**

[image: If I try open page from didSelectRowAtIndexPath without navigationbar - all work fine. But page open without navigationbar.]

[image: First what user see in work area when app init is **SocialPageViewController**.]

[image: in iOS 10 - when I tap to the row, instead of user's data page, opens the empty UIViewController with white navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

This time I find the solution by adding a delay before addSubView

```
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [ipadSHSidebarViewController setModalInMain: socialPageNavigationController];
    });
```